# Node.js - Getting data from mother query to a nested query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
    connection.query('select * from `test` WHERE `deny`=false',function(err,rows,fields){

for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
    if (rows[i].enddate == mydate)
    {
            msg = "message";
            connection.query('select * from `cash` WHERE `id`=test',function(err2,rows2,fields2){
            if (rows2[0].cash >= 30)
            {
                connection.query('UPDATE `cash` SET `cash`='+ rows2[0].cash-30 +' WHERE `id`=test',function(err3,rows3,fields3){
                msgsend(rows[i].contact,msg);
                });
            }
            });
    }


}
});
```

This is my code.
However, when I run my code
It shows an error like this: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Please help
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: at first you may have a look at *closures inside for loops, simple, practical examples*

Comment: where do I put the debug line?

Answer (score 0):

Try Debugging it firstly using

`console.log(rows)` and `console.log(rows2)` may be one of them is empty.

Also the error parameters are for reason ,you could catch error parameters and check them:

`if(err) console.log(err)
 else //rest of program`

Similarly err2

`if(err2) console.log(err2)
 else //rest of program`

This will definetly help in solving the issue

**EDIT**

Where do you put debug line??

Obviously where you have to debug

Like

`function(err,rows,fields){
   console.log(rows); //undefined if empty 
   if(err) console.log(err);
   else //rest code
}`

Comment: I can see the results by console.log if I put the console.log command outside the second query. However, I can't see the results of the query1 inside the loop of query2. The same is with the second and third query.

Comment: My code is like 

function(err,rows,fields){
debug of rows //success
  function(err2,rows2,fields2){
debug of rows //fail
debug of rows2 // success
    function(err3,rows3,fields3){
debug of rows2 // fail
debug of rows3 // success
    //inside code
    }
  }
}

Comment: Try storing the result of query 1 in temp variable `var temp = rows` than use it inside second query

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/)

```
connection.query('select * from `test` WHERE `deny`=false',function(err,rows,fields) {

    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
        if (rows[i].enddate == mydate) {
            myFuntion(row[i], function(msg) {
                console.log(msg) // Success!
            })
        }
    }
})

function myFuntion(row, callback) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            msg = "message";
            connection.query('select * from `cash` WHERE `id`=test',function(err2,rows2,fields2){
                callback(null, rows2);
            });
        }, function(rows2, callback) {
            if (rows2[0].cash >= 30)
            {
                connection.query('UPDATE `cash` SET `cash`='+ rows2[0].cash-30 +' WHERE `id`=test',function(err3,rows3,fields3){
                    msgsend(row.contact,msg);
                    callback(null);
                });
            }
        }
    ], function(err){
        if(err)
            console.log("Error: ", err);
        else
            callback("Success!");
    })
}
```